# Mocking an interface with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Can someone please help me with the below Mock object.
I want to write a mock test case for ServiceImpl class. 
I want to mock OrderIF interface:

```
public interface OrderIF{
    List<Order> ordersFor(String type);
}
```

The implementation of service is:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    private List <Order> orders ;
    private OrderIF orderif ; // this is 3rd party interface

    public int getval(String type) {
       //some code 

       // this returns a list of objects (orders)
       orders = orderif.ordersFor(type);

       // some code 
       return orders.get(0)
    }
}
```

My code give NullPoinerException:

```
public class ServiceImplTest {
     private List <Order> ll ;
     private service reqService ; 

     @InjectMocks
     private orderIF order;

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
         ll = new ArrayList<Order> ();
         ll.add(new Order("Buy"  ,  11 , "USD" ));
         ll.add(new Order("Sell" ,  22 , "USD" ));
         reqService = spy(new ServiceImpl());
     }

     @Test
     public void test() {
        String type= "USD" ; 
        when(order.ordersFor(type)).thenReturn(ll);
        q = reqService.getval(type);
        assertTrue(q.get().ask == 232.75);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where in your code is the NPE raised?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to mock the interface? It's an interface - you can just provide whatever implementation makes sense.

Answer (score 26):

`@InjectMocks` will not instantiate or mock your class. This annotation is used for injecting mocks into this field.

If you want to test `serviceImpl` you will need to mock in this way:

```
@Mock
private OrderIF order;

@InjectMocks
private Service reqService = new ServiceImpl();
```

To make it work you either need to use runner or `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in `@Before` method.

Comment: @ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class) instead of @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) since junit5 for those who don't know.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing that `order` is `null` and you're getting the `NullPointerException` here:

```
when(order.ordersFor(type)).thenReturn(ll);
```

For `@InjectMocks` to work and instantiate your class, you'll need to add a runner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {
    // ...
}
```

You don't have to use the runner, refer to [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

`@InjectMocks` doesn't work on interface. It needs concrete class to work with.

Also `@InjectMocks` is used to inject mocks to the specified class and `@Mock` is used to create mocks of classes which needs to be injected.

So for your case to work you have to do following change

```
@Mock 
private OrderIF order;

@InjectMocks 
private ServiceImpl reqService;
```