# Mock a method call called by another object which is autowired and interface in another class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I wanted to mock something like as

```
public class B {
   @autowired
   protected SomeInterface c; // interface


   public String methodToBeCalled(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) {
       ... some opertations;
       c.methodIWantToMock(x, y);
   }

}
```

so in usual cases, I would be creating a object of class B and then have initialized all other class as Mock, but since the c is a interface and autowired, I am unable to find a way to mock it yet, I looked into other posts but none of them was related to this case.

---

Is there a way I could achieve this in spring using Junit and Mockito only.

Comment: try mocking the Interface with `@Mock` annotation. Then you can use `Mockito.lenient.when(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).then()` on your desired method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking an interface with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782687/mocking-an-interface-with-mockito)

Comment: Also suitable: [Mock interfaces used by a concrete class with mockito](//stackoverflow.com/q/33807746)

Comment: You should use constructor injection instead of field injection.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend for a minute that you're not using Spring and you want to mock C.

1. it does not matter that C is an interface. Mockito is capable of mocking an interface -> it creates an implementation of that interface with "do-nothing" methods.

```
SomeInterface c = Mockito.mock(SomeInterface.class);
```

2. It does not matter that C is autowired. You can use set it using reflection.

```
    B bObj = new B();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bObj, "c", cMock);
```

3. Now that you've got your mock set up and set as a dependency within B, you can mock its methods however you'd like.

```
    when(cMock).methodIWantToMock(any(), any()).thenReturn("blah");
```

Now, let's consider that you're using Spring.

1. You should probably move to constructor injection:

```
    @Autowired
    public B(SomeInterface c) {
       this.c = c;
    }
```

2. Now for the pure unit testing approach, you don't need to use ReflectionTestUtils and you can just construct B with your mock.
3. If you are using Spring Boot, you can use @MockBean

   ```
   @SpringBootTest
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // if Junit 4
   // @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)  if Junit 5
   class BTest {

     @MockBean
     private SomeInterface someInterfaceMock;

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote unit test for your class B with JUnit4. This might help you.

public class BTest {

```
@Mock
SomeInterface c;

@InjectMocks
B b;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testMethodToBeCalled() throws Exception {
    String result = b.methodToBeCalled(new SomeClassA(), new SomeClassB());
    Assert.assertEquals("", result);
}
```

}