# How can i mock a servletContext in Mockito to be able to use addListener?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new MyServletContextListener());
        String skipCookie = System.getProperty("skipCookie");
        if(!StringUtils.equals(skipCookie, "Y")){
            servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
            servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
        }
        settingSystemProperties();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create tests for the above method to get code coverage on intellij, but i am never able to get past the `servletContext.addListener` line, as i keep running into the following exception:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.addListener(MockServletContext.java:734)
        at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.registerContextLoaderListener(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.onStartup(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:63)
```

How should i go about creating the Unit test? Below is what i have currently, commented lines are what i have already tried.

```java
@InjectMocks
ServletInitializer servletInitializerMock;
    
@Test
public void onStartup() throws ServletException {
    MockServletContext servletContextMock = new MockServletContext();
    //MockServletContext spy = Mockito.spy(servletContextMock);
    //MyServletContextListener myServletContextListener = mock(MyServletContextListener.class);
    //doNothing().when(spy).addListener(new MyServletContextListener());
    //Mockito.doNothing().when(servletContextMock).addListener(mock(MyServletContextListener.class));
    servletInitializerMock.onStartup(servletContextMock);
    //abstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(servletContextMock);
}
```

Comment: How about   
`ServletContext servletContextMock = mock(ServletContext.class);   
when(servletContextMock.addListener(any(MyServletContextListener.getClass())).doNothing();`

Comment: @Soenderby hi, i received the following error: 

IllegalStateException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'. Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.

Comment: I have been taking a close look at what you are trying to test, and it seems to me there is not any "original" behavior in this method. Rather it seems to execute a number of other operations, that should be unit tested. This seems to be a good candidate for an [integration test](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationTest.html) rather than a unit test. While this is a matter of opinion, I would suggest not to test solely for the purpose of code coverage.

Comment: Hi, yes i know that we should not be testing for the sole purpose of coverage, but my code is scheduled for a build, and if my code coverage does not hit a certain percentage, I cannot roll it out

Comment: This may not be an ethical suggestion, but code coverage is determined by the code that is _executed_ during tests, not necessarily the code that is tested. You could make a passing test that also runs this code.  
If you are particularly creative, you can perhaps even test something useful about the method, while avoiding the difficult parts.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can get my code to execute fully during this test?

Comment: Well I can only come with vague suggestions as I do not know much about servlets, or your specific context. But perhaps you could pass an actual instance of a `servletContext` and if possible set `skipCookie`. 
In a last ditch effort to give you the answer you were originally asking for, I see that `ServletContext` is an interface, perhaps this question on [mocking interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782687/mocking-an-interface-with-mockito) has some answers.