# How can I mock a Menu item in order to Unit Test a Menu in AndroidStudio (kotlin)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

I have a util object class for Menu:

```
object MenuUtil{

      fun updateMenuIconTint(menu: Menu, @ColorInt color: Int) {
         menu.forEach{
         it.updateTint(color)
        }  
      }
      fun MenuItem.updateTint(@ColorInt color: Int){
         var icDrawable = DrawableCompact.wrap(icon)
         icDrawable = iconDrawable.mutate()
         DrawableCompat.setTintList(icDrawable, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
      }
    
    }
```

How can I mock Menu and MenuItem in order to test those functions in a unit test?

When attempting to do so I am told that Menu is an interface.

Comment: This doesn't feel like enough for an answer, yet recommend looking at: [Wikipedia - Mockito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito)  The main example almost directly covers this topic.  This question [java-Mocking an Interface with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782687/mocking-an-interface-with-mockito) may also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also post your Test Class, it might miss a **@RunWith** Annotation, where you might miss **RobolectricTestRunner** or **AndroidJUnit4** (depending on how you test your classes that have a dependency to Android Classes like Context and other things)

Anyway - mocking an Interface is not a problem. Mockito or Mockk can do this without any problem.

Here an example with Mockk https://mockk.io/. Feel free to use other mocking libraries like Mockito Kotlin https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin

```kotlin
val menuMock: Menu = mockk()
val menuItemMock: MenuItem = mockk()
```

**Sidenote 1**:

In generally we don't necessarily unit test that an implementation is calling X functions, which should perform some actions (well as always - it depends, sometimes it makes sense to verify some function calls to other services and so on - but not always).

In your case though, you probably rather want to test, if your Menu Items, have your desired color - not how the implementation actually achieves this.

There are different ways, to check certain things.

You either test by checking some properties of an object, that they have the expected result - or you use an UI Testing Framework. In case of Android it would be https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso - if you don't use Jetpack Compose.

**Sidenote 2:**

Mocking Static Calls is a bit cumbersome, because normally you can mock an instance of an object and then verify calls on its public methods.

In a static context, there doesn't exist any instance.

Luckily Mockk or Powermockito, can mock your static classes, by doing some sort of wrapper to them.

And now, after a lot of "blah blah" here a working test.

```kotlin
import android.R
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkStatic
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.Test

class SomeTest {

    @Test
    fun test_tint_on_menu_item() {
        // given
        mockkStatic("androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat")
        val menuMock: Menu = mockk(relaxed = true)
        val menuItemMock: MenuItem = mockk(relaxed = true)
        val currentIconMockOfMenuItem: Drawable = mockk(relaxed = true)
        val drawableWrapMock: Drawable = mockk(relaxed = true)

        every { menuItemMock.icon }.returns(currentIconMockOfMenuItem)
        every { DrawableCompat.wrap(any()) }.returns(drawableWrapMock)
        every { menuMock.getItem(any()) }.returns(menuItemMock)
        every { menuMock.size() }.returns(1)

        // when
        val colorToSet = R.color.holo_red_dark
        MenuUtil.updateMenuIconTint(menuMock, colorToSet)
        // then
        verify { DrawableCompat.wrap(any()) }
        verify { DrawableCompat.setTint(any(), any()) }
        verify { menuItemMock.icon = drawableWrapMock }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the case of Mockito how can write this line:
val menuMock: Menu = mockk(relaxed = true)

Comment: import org.mockito.kotlin.mock

val menuMock: Menu = mock()


And if you have a static class

val mockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(DrawableCompat::class.java)